# Discord event on_member_join not working when a member joins the guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an event in my discord bot that sends an embed to welcome a member when the join the guild. No errors are produced but the event does not seem to work for me.

Here is the code for the event:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    """
    The code in this event is executed every time a member joins the server

    """
    embed = discord.embed(title=f'Welcome to {member.guild.name}',
                    description=f'{member.mention}, welcome to the server! \nMake sure to checkout the rules first. Enjoy your stay <3',
                    color=0x0061ff)

    if member.guild.icon is not None:
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url=member.guild.icon.url
            )

    await bot.get_channel(1047615507995562014).send(embed=embed)
```

I'm also using the following intents as well and have enabled them properly so I know that is not the issue with my code.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an Error, is because the **e** in **discord.embed** is lowercase

```
embed = discord.embed(title=f'Welcome to {member.guild.name}',
                    description=f'{member.mention}, welcome to the server! \nMake sure to checkout the rules first. Enjoy your stay <3',
                    color=0x0061ff)
```

Correct version would, obviously, be:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Welcome to {member.guild.name}',
                    description=f'{member.mention}, welcome to the server! \nMake sure to checkout the rules first. Enjoy your stay <3',
                    color=0x0061ff)
```

Comment: This actually didn't seem to solve my issue. I'm still not getting the embed after a member joins the guild.

Answer (score 0):

your bot is probably missing a privileged intent,go to your bot on the discord developer portal, then turn the server members intent on

Comment: Intents are configured in my bot, this is just a code snippet--not the entire program.

Comment: not on your code, but you need to turn it on in your developer portal, there are previliged intents that you may need to turn on